# Assign Single and double click events for NON-subclassed NSButton[if duplicate, answer this]

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbutton

How to assign Both single and double click events for a NSButton with two separate functions in cocoa (without subclassing the button)

Comment: No, no, no.  I'm saying use the body of that method for your multiple-mouse clicks problem, but change the action your button sends to add an NSEvent parameter.  No need to subclass.

Comment: shall we use  `- (IBAction)method:(NSEvent*)event` instead of `- (IBAction)method:(id)sender` ?

Comment: Here, I've gone ahead and answered.  Hopefully it's clearer than my comments.

Answer (score 4):

NSApplication can hand you an `NSEvent` for a given selector.  So, just amend the method you wish to add your double click logic to to support that event, and use its `clickCount` property to respond to any number of sequential clicks like so:

```
- (void)someMethod:(id)sender {
    NSEvent *event = [NSApp currentEvent];
    switch (event.clickCount) {
        case 1:
            //Handle a single click
            break;
        case 2:
            //Handle a double click
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: raising error :`-[NSButton clickCount]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100411d00`

Comment: Are you sure you've assigned the action correctly?

Comment: i used IBAction instead of void in your sample code

Comment: yeah working..but another problem... if double clicked, returns both single click and doubleclick events

Comment: Hm, I was afraid of this.  You may need to go the hard way and use an NSTimer to manage some interval of clicks and respond to them.

Comment: i tried as ` NSDate * newDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval newTime = [newDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"01/01/1970"]];
    
    if ((pressedButtonTime >= newTime-1)&&(pressedButton == sender)) {NSLog(@"Double clicked")}` for doubleclick event only.

Comment: @muruganandham Try using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` for the action to be performed on single-click. If you receive a second click, you can then use `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:` to cancel the delayed perform of the first action.

Comment: @jlehr thank you for your time. i wrote two functions inside the IBAction. Fired single click by pressing keyequivalent(space bar) and Double click by using mouse... this wat actually needed..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NSResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.Override `- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent` method.

> **mouseUp:** Informs the receiver that the user has released the left
>   mouse button.

```
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
 if([theEvent clickCount]==1)
 {
  NSlog(@"Single click");
 }
}
```

Comment: is there any way without subclassing?

Answer (score -1):

Below should fix your issue

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSButton *myButton;
```

Then later set the double action to your NSButton

```
[[self.myButton cell] setDoubleAction:@selector(showMsg:)];
[[self.myButton cell] setTarget:self];
```

Comment: NSButtonCell doesn't have setDoubleAction: